# Get average color of selected area in an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made some jQuery code, which can give average color of an image. But instead of getting average color of full image, I need to get the average color of circular custom selected area in that image. So that user can drag the custom circular area and get the average color of that specific area.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#i').on('load change',function(){
        var rgb = getAverageRGB(this);
        $('.one').css('backgroundColor',"rgb("+rgb.r+","+rgb.g+","+rgb.b+")");
        $('.onea').text($(".one").css("backgroundColor"));
    });

    $('#upload').on('change',function(){
        var $file = this.files[0];
        if($file!=null){
            var $src = URL.createObjectURL($file);
            $('#i').attr('src',$src);
        }
    });
});

function getAverageRGB(imgEl) {
    var blockSize = 5, // only visit every 5 pixels
    defaultRGB = {r:0,g:0,b:0}, // for non-supporting envs
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
    data, width, height,
    i = -4,
    length,
    rgb = {r:0,g:0,b:0},
    count = 0;

    if (!context){return defaultRGB;}

    height = canvas.height = imgEl.naturalHeight || imgEl.offsetHeight || imgEl.height;
    width = canvas.width = imgEl.naturalWidth || imgEl.offsetWidth || imgEl.width;

    context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0);

    try {
        data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    }catch(e) {
        /* security error, img on diff domain */
        alert('x');
        return defaultRGB;
    }

    length = data.data.length;

    while ( (i += blockSize * 4) < length ) {
        ++count;
        rgb.r += data.data[i];
        rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
        rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
    }

    // ~~ used to floor values
    rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r/count);
    rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g/count);
    rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b/count);
    return rgb;
}
</script>

<img id="i" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="300" height="100"/>
<br>
<input type="file" id="upload">
<div class='one'>
<a class='onea'></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any code in there for selecting a circular region of the image. Is that what you need help on? Stack Overflow does better when you have a specific, narrowly-defined question, not this kind of open-ended, I need a, b, and c done.

Comment: This bit of code could be useful: https://sighack.com/post/averaging-rgb-colors-the-right-way

Comment: Yes sir, code doesn't have any selection tool. I want a circular selection tool which when dragged over the image give its current position average color. Please help me out